# Opções para gerar documentação de API em Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5, documentação

Preciso de uma lib para gerar documentação de API no Laravel 5.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Laravel API Documentation Generator:** https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator

O repositório no GitHub inclui instalação, modo de usar e possíveis configurações que você possa achar necessário.

Answer (score 2):

uma das mais conhecidas e muito usada é o http://swagger.io/, inclusive estou usando neste momento em uma api aqui.